# "Webhook to Jenkins for Bitbucket Server" does only work when executed manually

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server, git-webhooks

I set up a Git repository on a local Bitbucket server and also set up a Jenkins server with a job that should be triggered when something was committed to that repository.

Unfortunately the job only runs when I manually hit the button "Trigger Jenkins" button in the Webhook settings.

As this works I assume there is no network/firewall issue and the "Jenkins instance" and "General settings" of the Hook are configured correctly. As the job runs fine when manually triggered I assume the problem is on the Bitbucket side.

What could be the problem when the manual trigger works, but no commit executes it?

Comment: I am having this problem also, did you found a fix?